How to trigger the new Format Panel (iOS 18) via a button press in UITextView?
I'm trying to programmatically trigger the appearance of the new Format Panel introduced in the WWDC24 session "What's new in UIKit" when a button is pressed.
So far, I've enabled text formatting by setting allowsEditingTextAttributes = true. This works for showing the Format Panel through the edit menu (when long-pressing or selecting text). However, I can't find a way to make the panel appear directly via a button press in the keyboard toolbar.
Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, how?
Here’s the (simplified) code I’m working with:
struct TextEditorView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: NSAttributedString

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textEditorView = UITextView()
    
        textEditorView.addToolbar()
        textEditorView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
        textEditorView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return textEditorView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.attributedText = text
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    
        var parent: TextEditorView
    
        init(_ uiTextView: TextEditorView) {
            self.parent = uiTextView
        }
    
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.text = textView.attributedText
        }
    }
}

extension UITextView {
    func addToolbar() {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()

        let formatButton = UIBarButtonItem(
            image: UIImage(systemName: "textformat.alt"),
            style: .plain,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(showTextFormattingPanel)
        )
        
        toolbar.items = [formatButton]
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }
    
    @objc private func showTextFormattingPanel() {
        // ? Show Format Panel ?
    }
}


There is no public API for triggering the display of the new formatting screen of a UITextView. When you select the new Format -> More... context menu in a UITextView, it results in a call to the private API _showTextFormattingOptions:. So one solution is to directly call that private API:
@objc private func showTextFormattingPanel() {
    // Show Format Panel
    self.perform(NSSelectorFromString("_showTextFormattingOptions:"), with: self)
}

This does work in a test development app. But this is far from ideal. It's quite possible this could cause an app rejection for using a private API. That's easy to avoid though will a little obfuscation of the selector string. The bigger problem is that the private API could change in a future iOS update which would result in the app crashing due to calling an unrecognized selector.
A much more difficult solution would be to create and present your own instance of UITextFormattingViewController. You would need to provide a delegate to handle all of the value changes and you would then need to manually apply them to the text view. This solution would be a lot more work. It also replicates all of the built-in functionality provided by the private API of UITextView. And the UITextFormattingViewController documentation contains no comments so it's really hard to know how many of the APIs work.

Thank you for highlighting the private API. And I can definitely see the potential issues with using it... It’s frustrating that the documentation for the new UITextFormattingViewController is essentially non-existent yet. I’ve spent days trying to figure it out and haven’t made much progress.
Given the circumstances, I think the best solution for now might be to use a different rich-text library instead.
